# Print a GUID variable

Tags: c++, guid

I have a GUID variable and I want to write inside a text file its value. 
GUID definition is:

```
typedef struct _GUID {          // size is 16
    DWORD Data1;
    WORD   Data2;
    WORD   Data3;
    BYTE  Data4[8];
} GUID;
```

But I want to write its value like:

```
CA04046D-0000-0000-0000-504944564944
```

I observed that:

- `Data1` holds the decimal value for CA04046D
- `Data2` holds the decimal value for 0
- `Data3` holds the decimal value for next 0

But what about the others?

I have to interpret myself this values in order to get that output or is there a more direct method to print such a variable?

Comment: Variables hold values, and values do not have a base.  It may be displayed as decimal, hexidecimal, binary, or any other base as part of the "printing" function, but the value itself has no base and so is _not_ "decimal".

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use the [StringFromCLSID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683917(VS.85).aspx) function to convert it to a string

e.g.:

```
GUID guid;
CoCreateGuid(&guid);

OLECHAR* guidString;
StringFromCLSID(guid, &guidString);

// use guidString...

// ensure memory is freed
::CoTaskMemFree(guidString);
```

Also see the [MSDN definition of a GUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/guiddef/ns-guiddef-guid) for a description of data4, which is an array containing the last 8 bytes of the GUID

Comment: using bstr as the prefix here is misleading as BSTR is a type and it is freed with SysFreeString(), not CoTaskMemFree(). I'd rename this to guidString, or guidStringCoTaskMemAlloc to be really explicit. OLECHAR is a vestige from 16 bit days, use wchar_t or WCHAR instead, better yet PWSTR as that includes the SAL annotation for "null terminated"

Comment: StringFromGUID2() can be used to avoid the allocation, it puts its result in a caller specified buffer. this avoids the possibility of failure and the need to free the result.

Comment: The link you gave says that Data4 contains values, not a pointer to an array as you say in the comment.

Comment: @SergeRogatch I think I wrote that because C++ treats array types similar to a pointer to a single element... I'll change the wording to make it less confusing

Answer (score 61):

Sometimes its useful to roll your own.  I liked fdioff's answer but its not quite right.  There are 11 elements of different sizes.

```
printf("Guid = {%08lX-%04hX-%04hX-%02hhX%02hhX-%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX}", 
  guid.Data1, guid.Data2, guid.Data3, 
  guid.Data4[0], guid.Data4[1], guid.Data4[2], guid.Data4[3],
  guid.Data4[4], guid.Data4[5], guid.Data4[6], guid.Data4[7]);

Output: "Guid = {44332211-1234-ABCD-EFEF-001122334455}"
```

Refer to Guiddef.h for the GUID layout.

Same, as a method:

```
void printf_guid(GUID guid) {
    printf("Guid = {%08lX-%04hX-%04hX-%02hhX%02hhX-%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX}", 
      guid.Data1, guid.Data2, guid.Data3, 
      guid.Data4[0], guid.Data4[1], guid.Data4[2], guid.Data4[3],
      guid.Data4[4], guid.Data4[5], guid.Data4[6], guid.Data4[7]);
}
```

you can also pass a CLSID to this method.

Comment: worked like a champ! I'm messing with some BLE structures that have  UUID aka GUID. I set:                                                      GUID *guid = &pCharBuffer->CharacteristicUuid.Value.LongUuid; and used the printf above. thanks for sharing!

Comment: I had to change each %02hhX into %02hX for it to work.

Comment: Due to integer promotion, `h` and `hh` modifier can be omitted.

Answer (score 17):

You can eliminate the need for special string allocations/deallocations by using StringFromGUID2()

```
GUID guid = <some-guid>;
// note that OLECHAR is a typedef'd wchar_t
wchar_t szGUID[64] = {0};
StringFromGUID2(&guid, szGUID, 64);
```

Comment: these are not BSTRs, those are freed with SysFreeString(), StringFromCLSID result is freed with CoTaskMemAlloc

Comment: Well, the advantage of using StringFromGUID2() is that you don't have to do any COM or BSTR string deallocations. You pass it plain ol' memory, and it writes characters there. An OLECHAR is just a typedef'd wchar_t.

Answer (score 14):

In case you prefer C++ way

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, REFGUID guid){

    os << std::uppercase;
    os.width(8);
    os << std::hex << guid.Data1 << '-';

    os.width(4);
    os << std::hex << guid.Data2 << '-';

    os.width(4);
    os << std::hex << guid.Data3 << '-';

    os.width(2);
    os << std::hex
        << static_cast<short>(guid.Data4[0])
        << static_cast<short>(guid.Data4[1])
        << '-'
        << static_cast<short>(guid.Data4[2])
        << static_cast<short>(guid.Data4[3])
        << static_cast<short>(guid.Data4[4])
        << static_cast<short>(guid.Data4[5])
        << static_cast<short>(guid.Data4[6])
        << static_cast<short>(guid.Data4[7]);
    os << std::nouppercase;
    return os;
}
```

Usage:

```
static const GUID guid = 
{ 0xf54f83c5, 0x9724, 0x41ba, { 0xbb, 0xdb, 0x69, 0x26, 0xf7, 0xbd, 0x68, 0x13 } };

std::cout << guid << std::endl;
```

Output:

> F54F83C5-9724-41BA-BBDB-6926F7BD6813

Comment: I'm assuming those std::cout.width()'s should be os.width() ?

Comment: You need os.fill('0') at the start,  and the width needs to be repeated for every byte of Data4.

Answer (score 12):

In case when your code uses ATL/MFC you also could use [`CComBSTR::CComBSTR(REFGUID guid)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0dsx8by.aspx) from `atlbase.h`:

```
GUID guid = ...;
const CComBSTR guidBstr(guid);  // Converts from binary GUID to BSTR
const CString guidStr(guidBstr); // Converts from BSTR to appropriate string, ANSI or Wide
```

It will make conversion & memory cleanup automatically.

Answer (score 8):

Courtesy of [google's breakpad](https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad/+/master/src/common/windows/guid_string.cc) project:

```
std::string ToString(GUID *guid) {
    char guid_string[37]; // 32 hex chars + 4 hyphens + null terminator
    snprintf(
          guid_string, sizeof(guid_string),
          "%08x-%04x-%04x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
          guid->Data1, guid->Data2, guid->Data3,
          guid->Data4[0], guid->Data4[1], guid->Data4[2],
          guid->Data4[3], guid->Data4[4], guid->Data4[5],
          guid->Data4[6], guid->Data4[7]);
    return guid_string;
}

UUID guid = {0};
UuidCreate(&guid);
std::cout << ToString(&guid);
```

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by [JustinB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884434/justinb)'s answer

```
#define GUID_FORMAT "%08lX-%04hX-%04hX-%02hhX%02hhX-%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX"
#define GUID_ARG(guid) (guid).Data1, (guid).Data2, (guid).Data3, (guid).Data4[0], (guid).Data4[1], (guid).Data4[2], (guid).Data4[3], (guid).Data4[4], (guid).Data4[5], (guid).Data4[6], (guid).Data4[7]
```

and then

```
printf("Int = %d, string = %s, GUID = {" GUID_FORMAT "}\n", myInt, myString, GUID_ARG(myGuid));
```

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is quite old, but would this work maybe?

```
inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& ss,GUID const& item) {
  OLECHAR* bstrGuid;
  ::StringFromCLSID(item, &bstrGuid);
  ss << bstrGuid;
  ::CoTaskMemFree(bstrGuid);
  return ss;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [UuidToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379352(v=vs.85).aspx) function to convert GUID to string. The function accepts UUID type which is typedef of GUID.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string
GuidToString(const GUID& guid, bool lower = false)
{
    const char* hexChars = lower ? "0123456789abcdef" : "0123456789ABCDEF";

    auto f = [hexChars](char* p, unsigned char v)
    {
        p[0] = hexChars[v >> 4];
        p[1] = hexChars[v & 0xf];
    };

    char s[36];
    f(s, static_cast<unsigned char>(guid.Data1 >> 24));
    f(s + 2, static_cast<unsigned char>(guid.Data1 >> 16));
    f(s + 4, static_cast<unsigned char>(guid.Data1 >> 8));
    f(s + 6, static_cast<unsigned char>(guid.Data1));
    s[8] = '-';
    f(s + 9, static_cast<unsigned char>(guid.Data2 >> 8));
    f(s + 11, static_cast<unsigned char>(guid.Data2));
    s[13] = '-';
    f(s + 14, static_cast<unsigned char>(guid.Data3 >> 8));
    f(s + 16, static_cast<unsigned char>(guid.Data3));
    s[18] = '-';
    f(s + 19, guid.Data4[0]);
    f(s + 21, guid.Data4[1]);
    s[23] = '-';
    f(s + 24, guid.Data4[2]);
    f(s + 26, guid.Data4[3]);
    f(s + 28, guid.Data4[4]);
    f(s + 30, guid.Data4[5]);
    f(s + 32, guid.Data4[6]);
    f(s + 34, guid.Data4[7]);

    return std::string(s, 36);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using C++20 formatting library, or {fmt}, here's a quick implementation of `std::formatter` made from the answers above:

```cpp
struct std::formatter<GUID> : std::formatter<std::string>
{
    auto format(const GUID& guid, format_context& ctx) const
    {
        auto it = ctx.out();
        it = std::format_to(it, "{:08X}", guid.Data1);
        it = std::format_to(it, "-{:04X}", guid.Data2);
        it = std::format_to(it, "-{:04X}", guid.Data3);
        it = std::format_to(it, "-{:02X}{:02X}", guid.Data4[0], guid.Data4[1]);
        it = std::format_to(it, "-{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}",
            guid.Data4[2], guid.Data4[3], guid.Data4[4], guid.Data4[5], guid.Data4[6], guid.Data4[7]);
        return it;
    }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

```
printf(%X-%X-%X-%X-%X", guid.Data1, guid.Data2, guid.Data3, &guid.Data4);
```