# Uuid conversion results in chinese letters

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, uuid, chinese-locale

I am new to C++ for just one project.

C++ is needed for an plugin and here I have to create an UUID. That is nearly the only thing were i need to create the plugin for.

My conversion from guid to str results in chineese letters.
The big Problem is, that there is no option to debug the plugin.

```
UUID guid;
CoCreateGuid(&guid);

char guidStr[40];
sprintf_s(
    guidStr,
    "%08X-%04hX-%04hX-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
    guid.Data1, guid.Data2, guid.Data3,
    guid.Data4[0], guid.Data4[1], guid.Data4[2], guid.Data4[3],
    guid.Data4[4], guid.Data4[5], guid.Data4[6], guid.Data4[7]);
std::string s(guidStr);

pUID->szFieldValue.Set(LPCTSTR(guidStr));
```

When I put in a string instead of this uuid, the string looks normal.

[image: Display Sample with the problem]

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452272/convert-boostuuid-to-char) may be it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly casting `guidStr` which is an array of `char` to `LPCTSTR` which is a pointer to `wchar_t` if you are compiling for Unicode.

Use `wchar_t` array and wide versions of the functions, so you can remove the cast:

```
UUID  guid;
CoCreateGuid(&guid);
wchar_t guidStr[40];
swprintf_s(
    guidStr,
    L"%08X-%04hX-%04hX-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
    guid.Data1, guid.Data2, guid.Data3,
    guid.Data4[0], guid.Data4[1], guid.Data4[2], guid.Data4[3],
    guid.Data4[4], guid.Data4[5], guid.Data4[6], guid.Data4[7]);
std::wstring s(guidStr);


pUID->szFieldValue.Set(guidStr);
```

Alternatively, use [StringFromCLSID()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1672698/7571258) to convert to string.